# PHP - Find Nth Occurrence of a DIV

Tags: php

At the moment I have the following

```
$elem = $reading->find('div[class=time-default]', 0);
$elem = str_replace("<div class=\"time-default\">","",$elem);
$elem = str_replace("</div>","",$elem);
```

This code looks for `<div class="time-default"></div>` and does various replaces on it. My question is, if `$reading` contains multiple DIVs with this class, how can I target the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, Nth one?

I am using this in conjunction with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ if that helps

Thanks

Comment: use `find(...,$n)` or `find(...)` without index and you get an array. See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

Comment: dom+xpath: `//div[@class="time-default"][5]` would give you the 5th div.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`find`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) is the index for the array of divs found:

```
$elem = $reading->find('div[class=time-default]', $index);//targets $index_th div
```